# elastic beanstalk change from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk application set up on AWS that was initially set up using PHP on 32 bit Amazon Linux. According to the documentation, it's not possible to change from 32 bit to 64 bit instances, which means I can't take advantage of the m3 instances which are only available in 64 bit.

I am assuming to change to a 64 bit environment, I will have to create a new Beanstalk application and delete the old one.  So my question really is: is there a way to do this while retaining the existing RDS instance?  If not, what process will I need to follow to prevent data loss?

Answer (score 1):

Create a snapshot for your RDS. Copy the snapshot ID for your database.
Then launch a new environment for a 64bit solution stack. For example if it is a Java application you could use "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.71 running Tomcat 7 Java 7
". If you are using the console, then you can create an RDS instance while creating the environment. The create wizard will ask you if you want a database. If you say yes, you will have the opportunity to specify the snapshot ID for your database. After your new environment is functional, you can terminate the old environment. The database for the old environment will also be deleted. But not to worry because you created a new environment with the snapshot of this database, the new environment will have its own separate database with the same data from the snapshot.

Let me know if you need help with any of the steps.